# Do not change current buffer when using vim quickfix window

Tags: vim

I use VIM in the development of C++ projects and configured a *compile shortcurt* as follows

```
map <F4> :w<CR> :set makeprg=make<CR> :make <CR>:cw 4<CR>
```

which builds my project and shows the quickfix window in case there are any errors.

However this will always make vim open the file containing the *first error* in my current buffer, which  is annoying when the error is not logically caused by the line indicated by the compiler but some other piece of code in the file that *is currently openened*. Can I prevent VIM from switching the currently openened file when jumping to an error (i.e. go to first error only if is contained in the current file, otherwise just open quickfix window). In addition: can I prevent jumping to the first error at all (again: just open quickfix window)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To prevent the `:make` command from jumping to the first error, call it with
`!` modifier,

```
:make!
```

See [`:help :make`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#%3amake), item 7.

Answer (score 6):

Besides using `make!` (with a bang), see also the ['switchbuf'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27switchbuf%27) option.

You could use `set switchbuf=split` to always use a new split when opening a file from quickfix.

Also check that you do not have set `switchbuf=useopen`, which might cause unexpected window/buffer changes while going through the quickfix list.